# Is there a manual "scan for Wifi networks now" in Network-Manager?

Tags: wireless, network-manager

**Background**

Most mobile OSes have a button to re-check for new Wifi networks. In Ubuntu I know I can

- type `iwlist wlan0 scan` and see the results printed
- disable and re-enable Wifi in the Network indicator
- type `sudo service network-manager restart` and restart the whole thing.
- wait for it to automatically re-scan for new networks

**Q:** Is there a way to nudge Network-Manager to re-scan for networks, besides nuking it as above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ever since Ubuntu switched from Unity to GNOME](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2018/05/ubuntu-18-04-the-return-of-a-familiar-interface-marks-the-best-ubuntu-in-years/), we can enhance the GUI shell with [GNOME extensions](https://extensions.gnome.org/).

Without the overhead of installing a new app and using only Network-Manager, the simplest solution is to install the [Refresh Wifi Connections extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/905/refresh-wifi-connections/).

Answer (score 5):

Networks are re-checked automatically. You do not need to press anything. You can wait for some seconds to see a new network.

To re-check immidiately you do not need to restart Network Manager. You can click "Disable Wi-Fi" and "Enable Wi-Fi", if you are so impatient.

Comment: I know the checks are automatic. I'll edit the question to reflect this, thanks for the reminder.

Comment: "You can wait for some seconds to see a new network.".  You mean wait for minutes (or at least, it feels like minutes).   The wait is too long; that is the problem.  What should be implemented in all Linux distribution is that when a user clicks on the Wi-Fi applet, automatically a new scan should be performed.

Answer (score 1):

You can try out **WiFi Radar** if you are looking for a more windows like wifi manager that has a scan button. You can download it from the software center or [click here](https://apps.ubuntu.com/assets/images/scbutton-free-200px.png) 
 [image]

Comment: The version coming with Ubuntu 16.04.03 LTS Xenial Xerus, 2.0.s08+dfsg-1.1ubuntu1, does not have a scan button.  Not sure if it continuously scans or not.